# Does a literal string for a command line shell count as a "program"?

Tags: discussion

As I compose this answer (https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/76418/4787) it occurs to me that I would never actually put that into a shell script. I would just type it at the command line, with the parameter filename at the end.

Does it make sense to count the characters in that command line rather than the length of the shell script?

Comment: I would assume that it needs to be in a shell script, because otherwise it's a snippet/REPL fragment, which are disallowed as answers.

Comment: That program also works with it put in a shell script.

Comment: @Morgan'Venti'Thrappuccino with the REPL environment in question being the shell?

Comment: That's how I would interpret it, yes.

Comment: This is a tricky case because it's using a "language" which isn't really intended as a general-purpose programming language, and so doesn't take a script file as input. I can't offhand think of any other interpreters which don't support reading their script from a file.